# Cordova android build is not working in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova

My app was working with out any issue. But today when I try to build my app for android I am getting this error.

ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir C\Users\MyUser\MyTest\bld\Debug\platforms\android\src\com\Test\mytest

I tried to clear the cordova cache and tryed and got this error.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyTest, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\MyTest>call "C:\Program Files\nodejs"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 4.2.1 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\3RZ4IYYB.KXY\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-mda
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 0.1.75
1>  ------ Package not currently installed globally.
1>  ------ Installing globally from source package. This could take a few minutes...
1>  npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
1>  npm WARN deprecated npmconf@0.1.16: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
1>  npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"4.2.1","npm":"2.14.7"})
1>  npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.7.2: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"4.2.1","npm":"2.14.7"})
1>  npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"4.2.1","npm":"2.14.7"})
1>  npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"4.2.1","npm":"2.14.7"})
1>  npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package has been discontinued in favor of lodash@^4.0.0.
1>  npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.6.2: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"4.2.1","npm":"2.14.7"})
1>  npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
1>  npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
1>  C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-cli -> C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli.cmd
1>  vs-mda@0.1.75 C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda
1>  ├── q@1.0.1
1>  ├── rimraf@2.2.6
1>  ├── ncp@0.5.1
1>  ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
1>  ├── adm-zip@0.4.4
1>  ├── fstream@0.1.28 (inherits@2.0.1, graceful-fs@3.0.8)
1>  ├── tar@0.1.20 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.8)
1>  ├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
1>  ├── elementtree@0.1.6 (sax@0.3.5)
1>  ├── request@2.36.0 (aws-sign2@0.5.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, tunnel-agent@0.4.2, qs@0.6.6, oauth-sign@0.3.0, mime@1.2.11, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, tough-cookie@2.2.1, node-uuid@1.4.7, http-signature@0.10.1, hawk@1.0.0, form-data@0.1.4)
1>  ├── ripple-emulator@0.9.24 (connect-xcors@0.5.2, colors@0.6.0-1, open@0.0.3, accounting@0.4.1, moment@1.7.2, request@2.12.0, express@3.1.0)
1>  ├── plugman@0.22.4 (q@0.9.7, underscore@1.4.4, nopt@1.0.10, rc@0.3.0, npm@1.3.4, cordova-lib@0.21.6)
1>  └── cordova@4.1.2 (underscore@1.7.0, nopt@3.0.1, cordova-lib@4.1.2)
1>  ------ npm install of vs-mda@0.1.75 from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\3RZ4IYYB.KXY\packages\vs-mda completed.
1>MDAVSCLI : error : ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Test\MyTest\bld\Debug\platforms\android\src\com\Test\mytest'
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have no idea. Couple of days ago it was working perfectly. Can anyone help me.
Thanks.

Comment: try [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **visual studio** cordova project check whether your id have the **android signature** in **config.xml**. If not rename the id and rebuild the project.

id = mytestapp.test  - wrong

id=**com**.mytestapp.test -**correct**

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you checked  'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Test\MyTest\bld\Debug\platforms\android\src\com\Test\mytest' folder ? Try to access here , check the rights of your user.